Why the warning: "FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise an error in a future version of pandas"?
I am not understanding why this particular warning is being raised, given the circumstances.  When applying a function to a numeric series, it raises FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise an error in a future version of pandas. Value '[0 1 1 ... 1 0 0]' has dtype incompatible with int32, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.
This is the function being applied:
def rush_hourizer(hour):
    if 6 <= hour['rush_hour'] < 10:
        val = 1
    elif 16 <= hour['rush_hour'] < 20:
        val = 1
    else:
        val = 0
    return val

This is the dtype and data that is stored:
print(df1['rush_hour'].dtype)
print(df1['rush_hour'].unique())
int32
[ 0 14  7 19 17 15 23  6 13 18 12 20 10 21 11  8  2 16  9 22  1  5  4  3]

So when I run:
df1.loc[(df1.day != 'saturday') & (df1.day != 'sunday'), 'rush_hour'] = df1.apply(rush_hourizer, axis=1)

I receive the FutureWarning of setting an incompatible dtype mentioned.  Given that I am applying a numeric value back, I do not understand why this message would be raised.  What am I missing?

Please make a reproducible pandas example, namely, provide an example version of df1 including the day column. See also [mre].

Also show the desired result and actual result if it's different.

I'm pretty sure I know what the problem is, but I want to see the details to make sure and test possible solutions.

It looks like the default behaviour of pandas when passing an a native python integer as data is to infer it as int64, based on this example and testing this locally.
So, when you run the apply function and return native python ints, pandas thinks that you are passing int64. In your example, the rush_hour field was inititally int32, causing the difference.
One way to avoid the error is to cast the original column to int64 before running apply.
df1['rush_hour'] = df1['rush_hour'].astype('int64')

You can view the available pandas dtypes here.

Thank you. I converted to int64 from 32 as you suggested, and the apply no longer raised the warning.  I also learned something new.  Thanks!
